# Bootstrap inheritance

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have never created or edited css.

Now I am using bootstrap and i want to use hero-unit in multiple scenario with different colors.

I really do not want to edit anything in original css. I want to just inherit hero-unit and make new class with a different color.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I believe you should be reading and watching [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/30-days-to-learn-html-and-css-a-free-tuts-premium-course/) before proceeding with developing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this isn't specific to Bootstrap but should give you a start on what you want. In your CSS do something like this:

```
/* Defined in bootstrap.css or wherever */
.hero-unit {
    background-color: Black;
}

/* These are yours in your styles.css */
.hero-unit.red {
    background-color: Red;
}

.hero-unit.green {
    background-color: Green;
}
```

Then you can then do this in HTML:

```
<div class="hero-unit red"></div>
<div class="hero-unit green"></div>
```

You can play around with this example here on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RrhyC/

Comment: you need spaces in the css between .hero-unit and .red, just a typo :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an article about specificity and inheritance.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Essentially, there's a point system based on how specific you are in terms of which element you are styling. Definitions that have higher point count has attributes of higher priority, overwriting attributes of lower priority.

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
  /*defined in bootstrap*/
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  /*my definitions are ignored because it's equal in points to 
  the one defined in bootstrap.*/
  background-color: red;
}
```

The easy way to get your definitions to stick is to put them inline in your html,

```
<div class="carousel-indicators" style="background-color: red;">
```

Or to append "!important" to your properties so that they get higher priority.

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

But they're generally considered bad practice.

So you can be more "specific" by applying more classes onto your div.

**In HTML:**

```
<div class="carousel-indicators custom">
  <div class="active>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In CSS:**

```
.carousel-indicators.custom .active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

This will inherit defined values from .carousel-indicators while giving values in .carousel-indicators.custom higher priority and preventing them from being overwritten.

However, if you use in SCSS:

```
.carousel-indicators .custom .active {
   background-color: red;
}
```

It will be looking for this target in HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
   <div class="custom">
     <div class="active">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

which might not be what you want.